# Can I start a Bitcoin Private Node using bitcoin-qt?

Tags: bitcoin-qt-setup

Currently I am starting a private node using:

```
bitcoind -regtest -port=11111 -datadir=.\data -rpcport=11112
```

I can't find the `-regtest` option in qt.

Comment: Pass it when you run qt

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by Pass it. QT doesn't like ``-regtest`` if I pass it in.

Answer (score 1):

```
bitcoin-qt -regtest -port=11111 -datadir=.\data -rpcport=11112
```

Comment: When I ran this command, it says that I am ''10 years 8 weeks behind". Is that means qt ignored -regtest and I am at the main net?

Comment: Regtest is a private test network that you create and control. All it has is a genesis block that was created 10 years ago, so what you see is that Bitcoin Core (both bitcoind and bitcoin-qt) only knows about that genesis block and thus believes it to be out of sync. This can be resolved by simply mining a block.